Can I use jpackage to build application images for native applications created with Graals native-image?
I have native Java application, build with native-image from Graal. As I have never worked with jpackage, I would like to know if I can use to to build installers with it for native applications too?

Jpackage can create msi or dmg or deb as described here. I tested with my javafx+graalvm project under windows and it is created the msi.
ozkan@HP-ENVY-2021-I7 C:\Users\ozkan\projects\swaggerific\target\gluonfx
$ jpackage -n nameofthepackage -t msi  --runtime-image installable

ozkan@HP-ENVY-2021-I7 C:\Users\ozkan\projects\swaggerific\target\gluonfx
$ dir installable
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is BC27-F52E

 Directory of C:\Users\ozkan\projects\swaggerific\target\gluonfx\installable

26/06/2024  22:46    <DIR>          .
26/06/2024  22:49    <DIR>          ..
15/06/2024  18:43        92,965,888 swaggerific.exe
               1 File(s)     92,965,888 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  139,368,534,016 bytes free

ozkan@HP-ENVY-2021-I7 C:\Users\ozkan\projects\swaggerific\target\gluonfx
$ dir
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is BC27-F52E

 Directory of C:\Users\ozkan\projects\swaggerific\target\gluonfx

26/06/2024  22:49    <DIR>          .
13/06/2024  22:40    <DIR>          ..
26/06/2024  22:46    <DIR>          installable
15/06/2024  18:43    <DIR>          log
26/06/2024  22:49        31,346,688 nameofthepackage-1.0.msi
15/06/2024  18:44    <DIR>          x86_64-windows
               1 File(s)     31,346,688 bytes
               5 Dir(s)  139,368,534,016 bytes free

When I installed the generated MSI which created this folder C:\Program Files\nameofthepackage and I can see my exe inside.
But I would suggest you to consider Gluon instead, even without javafx it can generate the package you want. Check these ymls.
